# mdadm: failed to set writable for /dev/md126: Device or resource busy

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software

yesterday my one of SSDs on my server came into a faulty state. Well at least `mdadm --detail /dev/md126` said that. Also `mdstat` showed `[2/1] [_U]` on one of raid partitions (md126 specifically). I couldn't create any files or edit anything because the raid was in read-only mode (for example if I tried to auto-complete anything in terminal with tab, it came up with message `cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system`) Raid's state was `clean, degraded` and the `sda3` partition was marked as removed and shown below as faulty.

I successfully reconnected the "faulty" partition by using these commands:

```
mdadm --remove /dev/md126 /dev/sda3
mdadm --add /dev/md126 /dev/sda3
```

The `mdadm --detail /dev/md126` now shows that both partitions are active, the state is clean and everything is normal. `mdstat` also - `[2/2] [UU]`.

But it seems the read-only problem is not gone. Can't create any files. Tried to remount the system with `mount -o rw,remount /` - no luck (`mount: cannot remount /dev/md126 read-write, is write-protected`). Also tried `mdadm --readwrite /dev/md126` - same result (`mdadm: failed to set writable for /dev/md126: Device or resource busy`).

I'm out of ideas. I need to bring back full functionality without server restart.

P.s. sda drive's iowait is high, %util usually is on 100 (well it was at least before crashing). Is that a sign of dying SSD?